# Java ignores default interface methods in an imported library and treats them as abstract

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, default-method

I am trying to use the [Functional Java](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava) library.

I just include it in `build.gradle` with

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.functionaljava:functionaljava:4.8.1"
}
```

and compile using `openjdk-15` and it just works... mostly.

The problem I have is the following:

I need to implement an `interface` ([`fj.Ord.Definition`](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/cd201cce91343302d928f72d31ead35021261de9/core/src/main/java/fj/Ord.java#L33)), which should be a functional interface - it has one non-`default` method and many `default` methods.

That means that an implementation via a lambda, or this

```java
new Ord.Definition<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public F<MyClass, Ordering> compare(MyClass a) {
        return b -> a.myCompare(b);
    }
}
```

should be fine.

What I get instead is:

*Intellij*: "Class 'Anonymous class derived from Definition' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'compare(A, A)' in 'Definition'"

If I try to compile it anyway, *javac*: `error: <anonymous MyClass$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method ord()`

This of course non only for the `ord`, but for the other 11 `default` methods as well.

If I try to implement them with `Ord.Definition.super` as in

```java
@Override
public F<A, A> prepend(A a1) {
    return Ord.Definition.super(a1);
}
```

I get the error `'java.lang.Object' is not an inner class`.

To note here is that the `functionaljava` library source code is full of these kinds of error (and many more) when viewed from Intellij in my project. Errors where Intellij complains about various mismatches between type variables and `Object` are also common there.

So my questions are:

1. How can I implement `Ord.Definition` as a lambda, as the library intends (or at least by using its `default` methods)?
2. What allows that library to be compiled despite how many apparent errors it contains?

**EDIT1:** Per request, here are some chunks of the referenced [`fj.Ord.Definition`](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/cd201cce91343302d928f72d31ead35021261de9/core/src/main/java/fj/Ord.java#L33) interface:

```
/**
 * Tests for ordering between two objects.
 *
 * @version %build.number%
 */
public final class Ord<A> {

  /**
   * Primitives functions of Ord: minimal definition and overridable methods.
   */
  public interface Definition<A> extends Equal.Definition<A>, Semigroup.Definition<A> {

    F<A, Ordering> compare(A a);

    default Ordering compare(A a1, A a2) {
      return compare(a1).f(a2);
    }

    // equal:
    @Override
    default boolean equal(A a1, A a2) {
      return compare(a1, a2) == Ordering.EQ;
    }
```

...

```java
    @Override
    default F<A, A> prepend(A a1) {
      return apply((a2, o) -> o == Ordering.GT ? a1 : a2, compare(a1));
    }
```

...

```java
    /**
     * Build an ord instance from this definition.
     * to be called after some successive {@link #then(F, Ord)} calls.
     */
    default Ord<A> ord() {
      return ordDef(this);
    }
  }
```

...

**EDIT2:** It turns out, in this case I can sidestep the issue by creating my ordering with either the method `fj.Ord#ord(fj.F<A,fj.F<A,fj.Ordering>>)` or `fj.Ord#ord(fj.F2<A,A,fj.Ordering>)` which each produce an `Ord<A>`. That does however not answer the questions I posed.

Comment: Show the code for `Ord.Definition`

Comment: I linked to it.
Here it is again: https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/cd201cce91343302d928f72d31ead35021261de9/core/src/main/java/fj/Ord.java#L33

Comment: Links eventually rot, or the linked code changes enough to invalidate your question for future readers.  You should include enough of the code that the question stands on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong dependency. `org.functionaljava:functionaljava` is retrofitted to work on Java 7 (and 6 according to the project docs). You need to use `org.functionaljava:functionaljava-java8` instead:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.functionaljava:functionaljava-java8:4.8.1"
}
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you. (I had previously tried including both `functionaljava` and `functionaljava-java8` but did not think to try including only `functionaljava-java8`.)